# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Ajax Form - Passing value to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is the final, which works! Thanks to  bob-the-destroyer.

I just had to change this :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#formSearch').ajaxForm(function (result) {
        $('#divArefresh').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn("slow").load('/Feed/Search');
    });
});
</script>
```

Into this :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#formSearch').ajaxForm(function (result) {
        $('#divArefresh').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn("slow").load(result);
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT: I thought that this :

```
// In /Feed/Index.cshtml
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Feed", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formSearch" }))
{ 
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search"  />
        <input type="submit" value="save"/>
}
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#formSearch').ajaxForm(function (result) {
        $('#divArefresh').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn("slow").load('/Feed/Search');
    });
});
</script>
```

With this :

```
 // In Controller/Feed/
 public ActionResult Search(string search)
    {
         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
                return Content("Variable : " + search);
            else
                return Content(":(");
        return Content("Pas ajax :(");

    }
```

Would do the trick, but it isn't. It always shows ":(". I'm really lost.

//////////////////////

I just wonder how to make this. I've tried many ways but I really don't manage to do it.
It's pretty easy to understand what I want to do :

I have a div which contains all the informations I want to show :

```
<div id="divArefresh">
    <div id="accordion-container">        
    @foreach (var i in @ViewBag.feedsItem)
    {
     ...  Things ....
     }
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to make a « search function », like this :

```
<!-- le champs de recherche -->
@{var options2 = new AjaxOptions()
{
    Url = Url.Action("Search", "Feed"),
    LoadingElementDuration = 200000,
    OnComplete = "divSearch",
    HttpMethod = "GET"
};  
using (Ajax.BeginForm(options2)) 
{
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Votre recherche"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="chercher"/>
}
}
```

Here is my « divSearch »

```
function divSearch() {
    $('#divArefresh').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn("slow").load('/Feed/Search');
}
```

When I submit something, it goes fine in my action :

```
public ActionResult Search(string search)
    {
        Users user = db.UserProfiles.Find(Session["id"]);
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var wordSearched = Request["search"].ToString(); --> NULL
            var feeds = (from u in db.Feed
                         where u.UsersId == user.UsersId
                         select u).ToList(); --> FINE
            var feedsItems = from u in db.FeedsItem
                             where u.Title.Equals(wordSearched)
                             select u;
            ViewBag.feedsItem = feedsItems.ToList();
            return PartialView("Search", feeds);
        }
        return PartialView("Search");

    }
```

BUT this :

```
Request["search"].ToString();
```

is always null when I try with the debugger. Even the « search » variable is null

If someone have an idea on how to make this work...

Kai23

Comment: what does your route config look like for this particular controller/action or whichever route it falls under?

Comment: It's the same as default. I don't really get your comment ? ^^

Comment: If you watch this in a client tool (like Firebug), what does it show in the console? Have you decorated the action with any attributes that aren't shown here?

Comment: When I add an [httpPost] before the Action, I got a 404 Not found in the Console. But when I don't add anything, it « works » (it goes in the Action)

Comment: I don't have a real error, I just can't retrieve any value from my form in the actions of my controller

Comment: Yeah, adding `[HttpPost]` would break it, since the form is set to `GET`. But, if you can watch the request being made in the browser, it helps to eliminate whether or not it's a model-binding issue

Comment: Another option is to add Glimpse to your project: http://getglimpse.com/ - then you can step through the routing & binding process.

Comment: Do you think it's a binding problem ?

Comment: `divSearch()` appears to be loading contents again: `.load('/Feed/Search')` - notice no additional url param.  But your form submission should also be sending a second request correctly so should show up if you just continue debugging for the next incoming web request.  Am I interpreting what's happening right?

Comment: divSearch() load the "search" view, which should contain the items I want to show. But while the param in my search box is null in my controller, I can't search anything in my database to return something to my view.

Comment: @Kai23: right, but the jquery `.load('/Feed/Search')` function runs another ajax call to fetch contents from `/Feed/Search'` (notice no url param added) and place it in `#divArefresh`.  Basically you're executing two ajax queries.  Try working with the `result` param on that jquery return method - the data should be in there.  At least I'm pretty sure that's what's happening.

Comment: @Kai23: IE replace `.load` with `.html(result)` or something like that.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer I'm really sorry, but I don't really understand. Do you think that the values of my request will be in the « result » variable ? If yes, how could I pass it to my controller ?

EDIT : Thank YOU !!